# Skyward Sword Floria Waterfall Dowsing

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I've defeated Ghirahim and am just messing around before fighting Demise and am not in hero mode. While exploring Floria Waterfall, which has the entrance to the Ancient Cistern, I was dowsing for rupees and the beige statue farthest from the bird statue on that side kept making noise. It's the statue that's rectangular on bottom and has an oval on top. There are four in total, two near the bird statue and two on the other side near the ancient cistern entrance. I have used every item I have on the statues and nothing has extracted the rupees from either item. I also used the beetle the pick up those yellow things dangling from the trees and the only thing that popped out was what was in the yellow thing. Nothing from the statues but the dowsing keeps going crazy on the statues. I already got the gold rupee up top so it isn't that. Also, an eye of the frog head entrance to the cistern is dusty but nothing I do will clean it off and I can't get up there to blow it. Anyone do this or can help?

Answer (score -2):

Try shooting an arrow into the eyes of the statues.